# Round cell values of a datatable (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have trouble rounding some cells from my datatable.
I want this round to 2 decimal places, as you can imagine. I will explain quickly how I charge data to the DataTable :

I have this function stored in a class:

```
Protected Friend Function cargarPref(ByVal id_Pref As String) As DataTable
    Dim cmd As String = "Select Material,Cubicaje,SubTotal,ITBM,Total from Preferencia WHERE Id_Preferencia=@id_Pref"
    Dim t As New DataTable
    Try
        con.Open()
        comando = New OleDbCommand(cmd, con)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_Pref", id_Pref)
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(comando)
        adapter.Fill(t)
        comando.Dispose()
        adapter.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error en la consulta: " + ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Return t
End Function
```

Ok, now I call it in my windows form:

```
 Private Sub DataCliente_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataCliente.CellContentClick
    If (Not IsNothing(DataMate)) Then
        DataMate.DataSource = Nothing
        mt.Clear()
    End If
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    If (DataCliente.Columns(DataCliente.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name.Equals("Empresa")) Then
        index = Me.DataCliente.CurrentRow.Index
        lblid.Text = DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("Id_Cliente").Value
        lblempresa.Text = DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("Empresa").Value
        lbldirecc.Text = DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("Direccion").Value
        lblcorreo.Text = DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("Correo").Value
        lbltel.Text = DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("Telefono").Value
        lblpreyd.Text = Math.Round(CDbl(DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("PrecioYD").Value), 2).ToString("N2")
    End If
    mt = data.cargarPref(DataCliente.Rows(index).Cells("Id_Preferencia").Value) <--HERE!!!
    DataMate.DataSource = mt
    PanelMaterial.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Now, watch as my values ​​are in my database access, Along With the datagrid of the program!

[image]
[image]
For some strange reason ... the data I have taken from the database , the program treats them as if they were integers.

How I can then round off those values ​​that are within the datatable, before printing in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered a solution , and I am going to show you how to solve this problem, if you need it (Before you do this , you must define all the columns you want to see on your datagridview !):

First, I create a class with public properties:

```
Public Class Preferencia
Public Property Material() As String
Public Property Cubicaje() As String
Public Property SubTotal() As String
Public Property ITBM() As String
Public Property Total() As String
```

End Class

Second , I create 2 functions and one procedural method :

```
 Private Function setPreferencia(ByVal material As String, ByVal cubicaje As String, ByVal subtotal As String, ByVal itbm As String, ByVal total As String) As Preferencia
    Dim item As New Preferencia
    item.Material = material
    item.Cubicaje = FormatNumber(cubicaje, 2)
    item.SubTotal = FormatNumber(subtotal, 2)
    item.ITBM = FormatNumber(itbm, 2)
    item.Total = FormatNumber(total, 2)
    Return item
End Function

 Private Function registrarPreferencia() As List(Of Preferencia)
    Dim lista As New List(Of Preferencia)
    For Each itm In mt.Rows
        lista.Add(setPreferencia(itm(0), itm(1), itm(2), itm(3), itm(4)))
    Next
    Return lista

 Protected Friend Sub FillGrid()
    DataMate.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataMate.DataSource = registrarPreferencia()
    DataMate.Columns("Material").DataPropertyName = "Material"
    DataMate.Columns("Cubicaje").DataPropertyName = "Cubicaje"
    DataMate.Columns("SubTotal").DataPropertyName = "SubTotal"
    DataMate.Columns("ITBM").DataPropertyName = "ITBM"
    DataMate.Columns("Total").DataPropertyName = "Total"
End Sub
```

Now the only thing is to call the method " FillGrid ()" when you want to print the data. And finaly, I resolved it!

[image]